# Could we use WCF over intranet?

Tags: wcf

I am trying to build a small app for a college with WPF, it is not a net app, and I am using the sql server 2008 for this purpose, and I am interested to know if WCF could be used for this purpose, and please let know why and why not to use WCF for this purpose.

The DB is processed in a Code library project that has all the classes etc.

Thank you for the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SURE!**  Why would you think it's *not* suited for this??

WCF can be used for almost anything - especially internet and intranet usages.

In intranet settings, you might want to look into using Windows authentication for simple auth, and the `netTcpBinding` protocol for top speed.

Comment: But, to my knowledge, wcf is a web hosting, hence, does it need IIS etc configured?

Comment: You can host IIS outside of IIS, such as a Windows Service: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729846.aspx

Comment: WCF can be hosted in a variety of ways (IIS, Windows Services, applications, etc.) See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx for more information on hosting WCF.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, from the site I get that I need to use  Windows service application, is that correct?

Comment: Windows Service is probably the best solution if you don't want to use IIS.

Comment: If you don't want to use IIS to host WCF, you can host it inside *any* kind of managed code - console app (great for testing!), WIndows Forms or WPF app - but typically, the best choice is indeed a Windows NT Service since it starts up with the machine and doesn't require a user to be logged on

Comment: Thanks Bob and marc_s, I would chose the work with the windows service project.  I hope this would be a new start for my coding life :P.  I will review on the windows service and start working on it tonight.  Thanks for all the help once again, any resource that can explain how to code a windows service in easy language for newbies like is good.  Thanks

Comment: This might be a good resource too http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649818.aspx

Answer (score 2):

WCF is merely an API to help you create hosted services and clients to consume those services or other services.  You could use WCF to implement a SOAP service that would be interopable with other languages such as Java, or you could do as marc_s suggested as use the Net TCP binding to create a service that is not interoperable, but that performs well in an intranet environment.

MSDN actually has a decent introduction to WCF its uses: [What is Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the information, the link you gave is of great value.